# What is the range of the following function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I have difficulties in understanding the concept of range. Let $f:\mathbb Z_{12}\to \mathbb Z_3$, $f(x)=x$. What is the range of it? Here is what i think: Range of $f$ is the set $\{a \mid a\equiv x \bmod 3 \text{ and } x=0,1,2\}$. Is that right?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what $f(x) = x$ means in this context?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I understand for example, if x=11, then f(x)=2. Is that wrong?

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are technically cosets in the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  The set you've written down is a set of integers, which happens to be all of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range is the set of values which you can get as result of applying the function. That is, for a given function $f:X\to Y$, the range is $\{f(x):x\in X\}$.

If I understand your function correctly, its range is $Z_3$.

Comment: Thanks, i think my definition of range is just an explanation of Z3, right? Then it is also true?